# What land formation was that?

Tags: gravity

At the end of the film *Gravity*, we see some land formations up close.  There's a particularly distinctive swirly island/sandbar that I'm referring to.  Shortly afterwards, Stone lands, and I'm curious if the land formation was distinct, so that landing spot could be identified.  Where did she land?

Comment: She had passed europe, but she lands in a weird unfimiliar country

Comment: She lands in asia. I think from the view vefore she lands its near the norh korea and. China boarder. Also looking at the land where she landed and he plant life. My bet is north korea/china western boarder. Real question is now, would north korea keep her as a prisoner or let nasa have her?

Comment: From memory looks like the Chosin Reservoir in N. Korea.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81430/23386.

Answer (score 8):

It was filmed in Lake Powell, near the border of Utah and Arizona. [This blog](http://jerrygarrett.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/gravity-filmed-in-lake-powell-arizona-not-exactly/) mentioned the [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1454468/) page listing the film locations used for the movie and gave some analysis on where the scene might have taken place.

Although we know where the movie was shot, there's no indication whether the scene was supposed to be there, story-wise.

However, there were radio transmissions that were interfering with the Houston communication, and they sounded Midwestern to me (although I might not be the best judge since I'm not from the US). The actual location still probably jives with the movie.

Here's an excerpt of [an interview](http://www.vulture.com/2013/10/alfonso-cuaron-answers-your-gravity-questions.html) with the movie's director, Alfonso Cuarón:

> The film was a metaphor of rebirth; literally, at the end, she goes from a fetal position [earlier in the film, when she floats after undressing in the space station], then in the water [shot at Lake Powell, Arizona, with significant postproduction alterations to make it green and lush and butterfly-filled]...

Comment: Lake Powell looks nothing like the lush green hilltops of the region Stone lands in.

Comment: @JackBNimble It was altered to look green and lush, but it was indeed shot there.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember when her capsule sinks to the bottom of the lake (about 10 meters) a frog swims up the bottom. Frogs normally don't frequent those depths except in Lake Titicaca in Peru where they are adapted to live at those depths. I guessing Lake Titicaca. I'd love for someone to confirm the landing spot.

Comment: Yet I wouldn't dare to impose that much zoological realism into this scene.